# How to determine if iOS has killed my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

If I put my iPhone app in background and bring it back to foreground after 4 or 5 hours it launches from the beginning instead of showing the previously visited page. But if I bring the app to foreground with in 2 or 3 hrs it shows the previously visited page. How to determine whether iOS kills my app or it has crashed due to some other reason.

Comment: Search the web for signals in C...

Comment: If it is freshly started then the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate method is called.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't say your app was killed (per-say) by iOS or crashed. I would say it sounds like iOS was cleaning up and releasing memory because it would have been running low on memory to run new processes. Like `Macmade` has stated look into signals in C

Comment: A proper solution for this scenario is not to detect if iOS has killed the app, since this is normal behavior (I am not talking about crashes). Instead implement state restoration: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Macmade suggested in his comment, you can probably put C UNIX signal handling code in your app to respond to a kill signal.

However, Apple does not intend for you to do this. When you get a notification that you are moving to the background you're supposed to fully save your app's state so you can restore it.

While you are in the background iOS can and will terminate you at any time without warning due to memory pressure. Sometimes you'll return from the background, and other times you'll get re-launched.

Another option:

If the device is a development device in Xcode you can connect it and open the console log to see if you crashed.

Answer (score 2):

"Killed" is a harsh term, and one that is potentially not appropriate for what happened. An iOS app can be in 5 states, and you receive messages in your app delegate letting you know which one of those you're in. At any point when your app is suspended, the memory you use can be reclaimed by the OS to use in other apps. This may be the "crash" you think you're seeing.

Additionally, your app may be too slow to transition to the background state and may be killed for those reasons. The best thing to do is run your app in the profiler to determine if it's actually crashing, or if memory is just being reclaimed. (Hint: If you re-open the app a few minutes after you close it and it's fine - and you don't consciously do any real background processing - then it's probably just the memory being reclaimed.)

The [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) explains it in detail, and I'm copying the relevant methods here for convenience.

- application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:—This method is your app’s first chance to execute code at launch time.
- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:—This method allows you to perform any final initialization before your app is displayed to the user.
- applicationDidBecomeActive:—Lets your app know that it is about to become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute preparation.
- applicationWillResignActive:—Lets you know that your app is transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to put your app into a quiescent state.
- applicationDidEnterBackground:—Lets you know that your app is now running in the background and may be suspended at any time.
- applicationWillEnterForeground:—Lets you know that your app is moving out of the background and back into the foreground, but that it is not yet active.
- applicationWillTerminate:—Lets you know that your app is being terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended.

Comment: "Killed" is not a harsh term. If the user force quits the app or if the OS terminates the app to make room for others, then the app really is "killed" (in the UNIX process sense of the term).

Comment: Good point. I meant harsh in terms of what may actually be happening (ie, it may not be watchdog "killing" the app, it may just be the OS reclaiming the memory in a more natural fashion).

Comment: But the OS reclaims memory by killing other apps.